# mvn flyway:baseline does not run my V1_0__baseline.sql script

Tags: mysql, maven, flyway

I have an existing MySQL database. I dumped the schema out to a file named `V1_0__baseline.sql` which I placed in `src/main/resources/db/migration`.

My `pom.xml` looks just like the example in the docs.

`mvn flyway:clean` will destroy any existing tables and remove the database.

`mvn flyway:baseline` will create the database but *only* creates the `schema_version` table -- it does not seem to run any of the SQL in my `V1_0__baseline.sql` file.

`mvn flyway:info` reports:

```
+---------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Version | Description            | Installed on        | State   |
+---------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 1.0     | baseline               | 2016-03-16 00:15:24 | Success |
| 2.1     | oauth integrations     |                     | Pending |
| 2.2     | base unified reporting |                     | Pending |
+---------+------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

From reading the docs that is not what I expected. I thought it would run all the SQL in my `V1_0__baseline.sql` file and give me my starting schema.

Have I completely misunderstood or am I missing something that would make this work as I imagined?

Comment: Which sentence in the docs made you believe this? (I am really curious as this is plain wrong, yet you are be far not the only one who has been mislead)

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply -- mad day.

All the words on this page: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/baseline

Partly I suppose because I was imagining it worked they way I described above. But even now you have confirmed for me that I was totally wrong I still read that page and find it a little ambiguous:

 "will cause Migrate to ignore all migrations upto and including the baseline version" -- possibly sounds like the "baseline step" is itself a kind of migration that establishes a baseline schema.